# Prove $\frac{1}{\exp(z)}=\exp(-z)$ by Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove $$\frac{1}{\exp(z)}=\exp(-z)$$ by Taylor series.

Since $$\exp(z)=\sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{z^k}{k!}$$
What can we do with $\frac{1}{\exp(z)}$?

Comment: the usual thing proved is $\exp (a+b) = ( \exp a  )(\exp b)$ which is fairly elaborate and needs care. Also $\exp (0) = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you will need to make use of discrete convolution, i.e. a way to take the product of two series and end up with a series with two indices (think of it as an extension of polynomial multiplication, or in parallel with its continuous counter part, integral convolution).

The formula for convolution gives
$$
\exp(z)\exp(-z)=\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-z)^j}{j!}\right)\\
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^k\frac{z^l(-z)^{k-l}}{l!(k-l)!}
$$
now notice that the summand looks a lot like the binomial expansion of 
$$
(z-z)^k=0^k
$$
but off by a $k!$. So we divide by $k!$ to compensate and find that the product is equal to 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{0^k}{k!}=1
$$ 
$e^0=1$ if you like, or since $0^k=0$ for every $k>1$ but is $1$ for $k=0$.

Comment: How is $0^0=1$?  It depends on how you define exponentiation, so you need to show that you are using a definition that makes $0^0=1$ work.

Comment: @OscarLanzi in your version of math is $e^0$ not 1?

Comment: @OscarLanzi your critique also applied to the other answer mine was just more explicit as to why, how else would we have $e^0=1$ if $e^x$ is defined by the power series?

Comment: I ask about the $0^0$ term in your summation.  In my math there are several definitions of exponentiation and not all are compatible with $0^0=1$.

Comment: Again, This will require you to have $e^0$ be whatever you chose to define it as, and not 1.

Comment: Still have a $0^0$ term in tour final summation tho.

Comment: Yes, as I should, since that is the *definition* of $e^0$

Comment: Note the other answer does as well

Comment: This convention is very standard as @qbert points out.

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem**
$$e^{ax}.e^{bx}=e^{(a+b)x} $$

(We will use the series definition and the cauchy product of two series, it works on formal power series also)

**Proof:**
We will take the product of the two series
$e^{ax}=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{a^{k}}{k!}x^{k}$  and
$e^{bx}=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{b^{k}}{k!}x^{k}$

$$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{a^{k}}{k!}x^{k} \sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{b^{k}}{k!}x^{k} =\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}c_{k}x^{k} $$
where $c_{k}=\sum\limits^{k}_{p=0}\frac{a^{p}}{p!}
\frac{b^{k-p}}{(k-p)!}$ multiplying by $k!$ we have
$c_{k}k!=\sum\limits^{k}_{p=0}k!\frac{a^{p}}{p!}
\frac{b^{k-p}}{(k-p)!}=\sum\limits^{k}_{p=0} {k \choose
p}a^{p}b^{k-p}$ by the binomial theorem $c_{k}k!=(a+b)^{k}$ so
$c_{k}=\frac{(a+b)^{k}}{k!}$, then we have

$$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{a^{k}}{k!}x^{k} \sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{b^{k}}{k!}x^{k} =\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(a+b)^{k}}{k!}x^{k} $$

**Corollary**

Take $a=1$, $b=-1$, then the result is $e^{0}=1$ by the series. Then $e^{-x}=\frac{1}{e^x}.$